# KeyPair from PEMKeyPair with BouncyCastle on Android

Tags: java, android, certificate, bouncycastle

Got exception on Android while converting PEMKeyPair to KeyPair:

```
 org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMException: unable to convert key pair: The BC provider no longer provides an implementation for KeyFactory.RSA.  Please see https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/cryptography-changes-in-android-p.html for more details.
```

This code works fine on vanilla Java on my desktop PC while fails on Android:

```
PrivateKey pk=null;

JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider("BC");

        if (object instanceof PEMKeyPair)
        {
            PEMKeyPair k = (PEMKeyPair) object;
            KeyPair key = converter.getKeyPair(k);
            pk = key.getPrivate();
        }else
...
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: And if you do not specify the provider this code still fails on Android?

Comment: Thank you! This solves my problem. But why setting provider makes code fail?

Comment: Just visit the [page](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/cryptography-changes-in-android-p.html) that is logged in the exception and this will answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

You will find the answer in the [page](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/cryptography-changes-in-android-p.html) that was logged in the exception message :

> Starting in Android P, we plan to deprecate some functionality from the BC provider that's duplicated by the AndroidOpenSSL (also known as Conscrypt) provider. This will only affect applications that specify the BC provider explicitly when calling `getInstance()` methods. To be clear, we aren't doing this because we are concerned about the security of the implementations from the BC provider, rather because having duplicated functionality imposes additional costs and risks while not providing much benefit.
>
> If you specify the provider by name or by instance—for example, `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7PADDING", "BC")` or `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7PADDING", Security.getProvider("BC"))` —the behavior you get in Android P will depend on what API level your application targets. For apps targeting an API level before P, the call will return the BC implementation and log a warning in the application log. For apps targeting Android P or later, the call will throw `NoSuchAlgorithmException`.

So to solve this error :

> To resolve this, you should stop specifying a provider and use the default implementation.

So in your case get rid of provider specification :

```
JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter();
```